# Jumpy touchpad cursor

Tags: touchpad

After running my laptop for a while, the touchpad response becomes terrible and the cursor become jumpy, I use Kubuntu 22.04. The problem also exists in Kubuntu 20.04.
I tried to change the touchpad settings, like: disabling tap to click and two finger scroll, but the problem persists.

The output of xinput list command is:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNA3602:00 0911:5288 Mouse               id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNA3602:00 0911:5288 Touchpad            id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB 2.0 Camera: USB Camera                id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                        
id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID 5 button array                  id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Regards,